# how to call function after ng-repeat select option value got selected

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a select tag:

```
<select
ng-model="department" 
ng-options='option.id as option.name for option in data.deptCategories'
ng-init="department=data.usercurrentDeptID" 
ng-change="change()" >
</select>
```

There will be object `deptCategories` which has all departments.

and `usercurrentDeptID` will have the user department id

So I am selecting that when the page loads. But the pagination is not working

When i `change()` from the drop-down to see other departments data the result is coming fine as i expected including pagination..!

Is there any way to call the `change()` function to get the proper data of selected value.?
instead of changing dropdown.! Is there any other way to call `change()` function when the selected triggers.!

```
ng-init="department=data.usercurrentDeptID"
```

Comment: Simple `ng-change="change()"` is working fine..!  i want to call `change()` with out `ng-change` as well..!! like `ng-blur` or any other which i don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution would be to have your `ng-init` call a function, which will do two things, set the department as it is currently doing, as well as calling `change()`, since this is what is loading the paged data. You will leave the `ng-change` method, since this will handle subsequent changes to the drop down, but the new `ng-init` method will take care of the original load.

.html

```
<select
    ng-model="department" 
    ng-options='option.id as option.name for option in data.deptCategories'
    ng-init="initDepartment(data.usercurrentDeptID)" 
    ng-change="change()" >
</select>
```

.js

```
// in your controller
$scope.initDepartment = function (currentDeptId) {
    $scope.department = currentDeptId;
    $scope.change();
}
```

Comment: You are simply amazing thank you so much. I really appreciate your skills.

Comment: I tried this `ng-init="department=data.usercurrentDeptID,change();"`:  but seems like its wrong

Comment: You can do that as well, just change the comma to a `;`. I just like the function because it moves the logic out of the view.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange) ng-change will not be evaluated if the model is changed programmatically and not by a change to the input value. You can use $scope.$watch to handle changes when the model changes.

```
$scope.$watch("department", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    //handle changes
    $scope.change();
});
```

With $scope.$watch you will not be needing the ng-change as $scope.$watch will be handling the change event.

Comment: If you end up doing it this way, you will want to remove the `ng-change` since the `$watch` will be handling that change event.

Comment: You are right, let me update the answer as it is easier to follow answers than comments.